# Who place the data onto the cache?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Like we have locality of reference on which basis this data is copied to cache but who is responsible for this.

Is there any h/w or is there any s/f which perform this action?

Answer (score 2):

The CPU reads/writes data into the cache when an instruction that access the memory is executed.
So it's an on-demand service, data is moved upon a request.
It then try to keep the data in the cache [as long as possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#WRITEPOLICIES) until there is no more space and a [replacement policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies) is used to evict a line in favor of new data.
The minimal unit of data transferred is called [line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_entries) and it is usually bigger than the register size (to improve locality).

Some CPUs have a [prefetcher](https://superuser.com/questions/1156538/does-intel-q8200-have-cache-prefetcher/1158032#1158032) that, upon recognition of specific memory access patterns, try to automatically move data into the cache *before* it is actually requested by the program.

Some architecture have instructions that performs as *hints* for the CPU to prefetch data from a specific address.
This let the software have a minimal control over the prefetching circuitry, however if the software wants to just move data into the cache it only has to read the data (the CPU will cache it, if caching is enabled in that region).